# primeng p-column get p-radioButton value

Tags: angular, primeng

i have an array in my .ts

```
 this.cars = [{ 'id': '1', 'vin': 't2se111' }, { 'id': '2', 'vin': 'tse' }, { 'id': '3', 'vin': 'tse22' }];
```

now i  show it as datatable in .html

```
<p-dataTable [value]="cars" [editable]="true">
<p-column field="vin" header="人次" [editable]="true"></p-column>
<ng-template let-rowdata="rowData" pTemplate="body" field="test">
   <p-radioButton name="{{rowdata['id']+'record'}}" label="mylabe1" value="val1"></p-radioButton>
   <p-radioButton name="{{rowdata['id']+'record'}}" label="mylabe2" value="val2"></p-radioButton>
</ng-template>
</p-dataTable>
```

i can easily edit the vin value in cars , but how can i get the radioButton's value ?

i'v tried

```
this.cars = [{ 'id': '1', 'vin': 't2se111' ,'col':'val1'}, { 'id': '2', 'vin': 'tse' ,'col':'val2'}, { 'id': '3', 'vin': 'tse22','col':'val1' }];
```

and .ts

```
<p-dataTable [value]="cars" [editable]="true">
<p-column field="vin" header="人次" [editable]="true"></p-column>

<ng-template let-rowdata="rowData" pTemplate="body" field="col">
   <p-radioButton name="{{rowdata['id']+'record'}}" label="mylabe1" value="val1"></p-radioButton>
   <p-radioButton name="{{rowdata['id']+'record'}}" label="mylabe2" value="val2"></p-radioButton>
</ng-template>
```

but i failed can anyone teach me how to do ?

Comment: hi, do you use some library except angular ?

Comment: @DrNio No i just use angular

Comment: You should specify ngModel for p-radioButton and use it in .ts file

Comment: but ngModel can't use {{ }} , it will occur error QQ

Comment: `<p-radioButton #foo (click)="myMethod(foo.value)" name="{{rowdata['id']+'record'}}" label="mylabe1" value="val1"></p-radioButton>` or

`<p-radioButton (click)="myMethod(val1)" name="{{rowdata['id']+'record'}}" label="mylabe1" value="val1"></p-radioButton>`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i found that

```
this.cars = [{ 'id': '1', 'vin': 't2se111' ,'col':'val1'}, { 'id': '2', 'vin': 'tse' ,'col':'val2'}, { 'id': '3', 'vin': 'tse22','col':'val1' }];
```

and html

```
<ng-template let-rowdata="rowData" pTemplate="body">
  <p-radioButton name="{{'record'+rowdata['id']}}" label="label1" value="val1" [(ngModel)]="rowdata.test"></p-radioButton>
  <p-radioButton name="{{'record'+rowdata['id']}}" label="label1" value="val2" [(ngModel)]="rowdata.test"></p-radioButton>
</ng-template>
```

solve my problem, thx for answer~